# Mensa online IQ test question nº 35

Tags: logical-deduction

http://www.mensa.fi/iq/index_2.html
what is the logic?
I have no idea for this :/
any hint?

Comment: Puzzles posted here need, if at all possible, to be self-contained. Please provide an image, or a careful enough description that we don't need an image, or something of the sort. (Please also respect copyright. If you cannot _both_ provide us with the question _and_ respect copyright, then you should not be asking the question here.)

Comment: When I follow your link I get a question that is entirely trivial and I suspect is intended only as an example (there's a 3x3 grid with each row having _the same symbol_ in each place, the bottom right entry is blank, and there are a list of options for filling it which include the symbol in the other two bottom-row spaces. But I suspect that what I see when following that link is not the question you're intending to ask about.

Comment: Yep I'm also only seeing the trivial problem that @GarethMcCaughan mentioned. Edit: Ah the question title specifies question number 35. I guess the only way to find it is by initiating the test at the provided link haha

Comment: Hello, I found this #35 question: ![Puzzle#35](https://imgur.com/a/wpYj0HC).  Is that the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it (provided dummy answers to the 34 first questions to finally get 35th question which is the one you are intersted in, if I understand well)

> This works by column: 
>  
>  1. Flip the first element of the column up-down (for example, the first symbol becomes a big square with a little square at bottom right, 
>  
>  2. Then stack with the 2nd element of the column, 
>  
>  3. And "XOR" them: when one line is on one picture only, it is also on 3rd picture. When one line is present on both pictures, it disappears. For example, first picture and second one both have a left hand line, so there is no left hand line on 3rd element. Second example: first picture has a top line, second one does not: so the 3rd picture has a top line... Clear ? ;)

So the solution of the quizz is

> the last (6th) element. Quite easy to verify with the "middle" vertical line: it is plain on 1st picture, and dashed on 2nd one. This results in a dashed vertical middle line for 3rd element: only one proposal out of the 6 has this, which is the last proposal